# Converting PBF to Shapefile with name:xx tags as a column in the attributes

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr2ogr, pbf

I have a PBF file containing only [rivers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:waterway%3Driver) information (extracted using osmosis when waterway=river).

A conversion of this PBF to SHP works fine with ogr2ogr when I am selecting fields like "osm_id" and "name". However, I would like to have the name of the rivers in different languages in the attribute table. The available translations appears in the "other_tags" column like this example: *"name:en"=>"The Thames","name:fr"=>"La Tamise"*.

Is it possible to create a SHP (or any other format) where the different translation of the rivers name would appear in different columns (eg. name:en, name:fr)?

This gdal command:

```
ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' -sql 'select osm_id,name,"name:en" from lines where waterway="river"' rivers.shp rivers.osm.pbf --config ogr_interleaved_reading yes -lco ENCODING=UTF-8
```

returns the following error: **ERROR 1: Unrecognized field name name:en**

Answer (score 1):

Edit osmconf.ini file:

> ```
> # Uncomment to avoid laundering of keys ( ':' turned into '_' )
> attribute_name_laundering=yes
> ```

Add fields

> ```
> # keys to report as OGR fields
> attributes=name,highway,waterway,aerialway,barrier,man_made,railway,name:ru,name:en
> ```

GDAL command:

> ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress -f "ESRI Shapefile"
> railway_stations_ru.shp ukraine-latest.osm.pbf -lco ENCODING=UTF-8
> -sql "SELECT osm_id, name, name_ru, name_en, other_tags FROM points WHERE railway='station'"